# Should we be careful not to mispunctuate prayers?

Tags: tefilla, grammar-dikduk, song-poetry

There are a few times that we ten to (from personal experience) punctuate parts of songs/ piyutim/ prayers wrong.

For example, in Modeh Ani people tend to punctuate as follows:

> שהחזרת בי נשמתי בחמלה רבה, אמונתיך
> Meaning: "...That You returned my soul to me with great grace, Your belief."

Instead of the correct punctuation:

> שהחזרת בי נשמתי בחמלה, רבה אמונתיך
> Meaning: "...That You returned my soul to me with grace, great is Your belief"

Another case is Adon Olam, where it is sometimes punctuated:

> אדון עולם/ אשר מלך; בטרם כל/ יציר נברא
> Meaning: "Master of the world/ Who ruled; Before everything/ a creation was created

Instead of the correct:

> אדון עולם/ אשר מלך; בטרם/ כל יציר נברא
> Meaning: "Master of the world/ Who ruled; Before/ all creations were created

There are other examples, some with more 'problematic' mistakes, others with lesser ones.

My question is, is it problematic/ *assur* to sing or say prayers and songs in such a way?

---

There are many other times that we mispunctuate, especially in cases where it doesn't change the meaning, or where the new punctuation doesn't mean anything. An answer about such a case would also be appreciated, but I am especially interested in a case where it does change the meaning.

Comment: Wood u rite w/ slopy gramar in an lettr 2 a reel deal king?

Comment: @DoubleAA, of course not. I would also make sure I'm pronouncing all of my words correctly, and also mean what I say. Even so, these things aren't necessarily always Assur ('just' problematic), and very rarely Me'Akev

Comment: Do you want to call it a bittul aseh of yirat hashem? Looking for a formal prohibition may be missing the point. If you understand what you're saying when you pray you won't make mistakes, and if you don't understand what you're saying then you're largely wasting your time anyway. If you make an honest mistake God knows your intentions and loves you anyway.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'd like to know if I should stop using specific tunes because they cause mispronunciations, or if because I (and HaShem) understand what I mean, it's 'not a big deal'

Comment: Wood u sang w/ slopy gramar in an lettr 2 a reel deal king?

Comment: See Magen Avraham 56 S”K 8

Comment: Adon olam might be different because it's written with a meter

Comment: @DoubleAA Again, no. But, as you and I both said, HaShem knows what we mean. And so do I, so I have the right kavana. So this might be different than 'melech basar v'dam'

Comment: The reel deal king nose what eye mene two, as shoan bye you're under standing its.

Comment: @DoubleAA not if you had written something in such a way that it meant something other than what you were actually saying. Then I Would understand it how it was written, I assume. Also, understanding what you're writing now involves some torach and I don't know if I'd be able to do it if you were speaking